# Can I define Alt key menu keyboard shortcuts for bookmarks in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

Can I define <kbd>Alt</kbd> key menu keyboard shortcuts for bookmarks in ***Firefox 3.6***?

Example:

[Tropical Weather](http://www.wunderground.com/tropical/) is in the Bookmarks menu. A keyboard-only way to use this bookmark is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <press down arrow key a number of times> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I would like to be able to do it this way:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Where the association of the underlined letter in the bookmark menu, <kbd>W</kbd>, to *Tropical Weather*  is user-defined.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by prefixing the shortcut in question with "w" or "W": *Tropical Weather* -> *wTropical Weather*. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will work as it will immediately open if there is only *one* shortcut that begins with "w". This is a general Windows feature, but with bookmarks we have direct control over the content of a menu, the booksmarks menu.

HowTo:

1. Open menu *Booksmarks* -> *Show All Bookmarks*.
2. Click on "Booksmarks Menu" in the left panel (it is in the tree *All Bookmarks*).
3. Select the bookmark in question on the right, Tropical Weather / `http://www.wunderground.com/tropical/` in the example.
4. Add the prefix in the field *Name*, "w" in the example - the result is *wTropical Weather*.

If there is more than one shortcut that begins with "w" then rename the other shortcut(s) to not start with "w".

Answer (score 1):

Not normally, but the Firefox add-on *[access key akari](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/141859/)* lets you do that.

Comment: This add-on is for the bookmark toolbar, not the bookmark menu. But it could be useful nonetheless.